# Internal Hard Drive Clicking and Unreadable

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

So it seems my 3.5" SATA drive is dead. I woke to the sound of it clicking this morning and powered off. When I turned back on, it clicked again continuously and refused to be recognise. Is this the read/write heads or would a PCB replacement be likely to work?  Or indeed would I have any luck doing anything internally?
Is there anything I can do to get the data off this drive?

Comment: It died. Smash it with a hammer for security, then recycle it. Your backup is now required. Or investigate data recovery specialists, if you have no backup. They charge per MB, are not cheap & make no guarantees of full recovery.

Comment: @Tetsujin while this is true, there's a few 'odd' things they  can try if they have no backup. The freezer option is one that worked for me once, and gave me access to a drive for a few hours to pull files off before it finally gave up the ghost. -- Seal the drive in a bag/air proof container. Stick it in the freezer for 24-48 hours. Take it out the freezer, ensure no condensation gathers on the drive. Stick it in a caddy and run ddrescue to pull a image as fast as possible. Don't bother with anything other than an image of the disk, as you've only got limited time (If this even works).

Comment: @djsmiley2k - I'd call that 'clutching at straws' but it's worth a try. So is shaking the chicken bones left-handed, just after sunset on a Tuesday, facing East ;-) Best strategy is still "recover to a new drive from your backup."

Comment: So a PCB replacement is a waste of time then?

Comment: Most likely yes. YOu would need an identical PCB and possibly identical firmware (so any random drive of the same model might not due). And clicking is often mechanical failure, though a PCB bug can also cause drive resets.  And it might help to add if you do have backups, if they are recent, and how important the data is. If you backups and important that stop using the drive at once and call an (sadly expensive) attempted recovery service.  If you have last weeks backups and only want a most recent save game then freezer, oven and praying might help.